# Conditional attribute/attribute value in Handlebars template

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I have a handlerbars partial `_button` and I want to conditionally pass in `style` attribute or it's value to this partial.
I have tried this code, but it would not work resulting in an error

```
{{> _button
    classes="overflow-hidden"
    {{#if hasMaxWidth}}style="max-width:83px"{{/if}}
}}
```

The error goes as follows:

```
Parse error on line 1:
...s="overflow-hidden" {{#if hasMaxWidt
-----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'OPEN_BLOCK'
```

Is there a way to conditionally pass in value or whole attribute to a partial in handlebars?

Comment: Handlebars does not support nested mustaches, so your approach won't work. How about passing `hasMaxWidth` does to the `_button` partial and have _it_ conditionally render the `max-width:83px`?

Comment: @76484 This is a valid approach, thanks, but `_button` is general 'component' and I wouldn't wan't  this kind of logic inside of it, but as I see from the code that would work most likely.

Comment: In order to keep the `max-width:83px` out of the `_button` partial, I think you would need to create a custom helper - albeit a very simple one.

Answer (score 0):

Using `registerHelper` you can do that try below code it's help you !

```
{{> _button
classes="overflow-hidden" style="{{#ifCompare hasMaxWidth}} max-width:83px; {{else}}{{/ifCompare}}"
}}
```

//in your `server.js` file you need to create `registerHelper`

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCompare', function (V1, options) {
    if (V1) {
        return options.fn(this);
    }
    else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```